# Loading External Shaders Using THREE.JS

Tags: three.js, glsl

I am trying to make a THREE.JS scene with GLSL shaders applied, but am having trouble figuring out how to make it load my shaders. The scene appears to work, but the shaders don't do what they're supposed to. I'm using a [shader loader](http://www.davideaversa.it/2016/10/three-js-shader-loading-external-file/) function I found that uses pure THREE.JS instead of AJAX or Jquery.

Here is the main javascript for my scene.

```js
var container,
 renderer,
 scene,
 camera, 
 light,
 mesh,
 controls,
 start = Date.now(),
 fov = 30;

window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {

 container = document.getElementById( "container" ); 

 if(!Detector.webgl) {
  Detector.addGetWebGLMessage(container);
  return;
 }

 //get the width and height
 var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

 //sphere params
 var radius = 20,
  segments = 4,
  rotation = 6;

 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 //             ASPECT RATIO
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10000);
 camera.position.z = 100;

 scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333));

 light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
 light.position.set(100, 3, 5);
 scene.add(light);

 ;
 
 ShaderLoader('./shaders/vertex.vert', './shaders/fragment.frag')
 
 material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
   uniforms: {
    tExplosion: {
     type: "t",
     value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/explosion.png' )
    },
    time: { //float initialized to 0
     type: "f",
     value: 0.0
    }
   },
   vertexShader: ShaderLoader.vertex_text,
   fragmentShader: ShaderLoader.fragment_text
 } );

 mesh = new THREE.Mesh( 
  new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( radius, segments ),
  material
  );
 scene.add( mesh );

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
 renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

 
 //update renderer size, aspect ratio, and projectionmatrix, on resize
 window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
   HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 });
 
 controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

 container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

 render();

} );

function render() { 
  material.uniforms[ 'time' ].value = .00025 * ( Date.now() - start );
  controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// This is a basic asyncronous shader loader for THREE.js.
function ShaderLoader(vertex_url, fragment_url, onLoad, onProgress, onError) {
    var vertex_loader = new THREE.XHRLoader(THREE.DefaultLoadingManager);
    vertex_loader.setResponseType('text');
    vertex_loader.load(vertex_url, function (vertex_text) {
        var fragment_loader = new THREE.XHRLoader(THREE.DefaultLoadingManager);
        fragment_loader.setResponseType('text');
        fragment_loader.load(fragment_url, function (fragment_text) {
            onLoad(vertex_text, fragment_text);
        });
    }, onProgress, onError);
}
```

But when my scene loads, it is just a red sphere with no lighting or applied shaders... What am I doing wrong? I'm new to all of this so it is probably something easily noticeable for someone more experienced, but I have searched and searched and been experimenting and can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `material.needsUpdate = true` after you load your shader.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet show error of the WebGL detector.
Are you loading that library?
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/Detector.js

Comment: Yes I am including all the libraries necessary, as the shader loader is only using three.js. everything else is functioning, simply not loading the shaders properly. The scene does not look as it should with the noise function I have in my vertex shader